# Dokuwiki ExtensionManager: "Extension directory is not writable"

Tags: dokuwiki

I just installed the latest version of Doku on a **Win16 server** running **IIS 10**.
However, the Extension Manager is reporting the error below.  I have followed the instruction [here](https://www.dokuwiki.org/install:permissions) to configure the directories as documented (writable for IUSR), but no luck.

There seem to be very limited help from the Doku site.  Can anyone help me to make this go away, because I think this error is preventing me from installing addition plug-ins.  Thanks!

[image]